# KeyPress not being detected

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

My code is supposed to record keystrokes while another program runs - For example, when I press the "Q" key while in a game, my code should mark down what time I did so.  Later on, I can look inside the log to see when the keystroke occured.  (I am using .Net 4.5 framework.)

The keyPress is not being detected in my code below - How can I fix this?

```
Public Class MainForm
    Dim startTime As DateTime

    Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If Button1.Text = "Start" Then
            startTime = DateTime.Now
            TimerLoad.Start()
            Button1.Text = "Stop"
        Else
            TimerLoad.Stop()
            Button1.Text = "Start"
            Dim FileNumber As Integer = FreeFile()
            FileOpen(FileNumber, "C:\Users\JasonValidia\Documents\MontageTimer.txt", OpenMode.Output)
            For Each Item As Object In ListBox1.Items
                PrintLine(FileNumber, Item.ToString)
            Next
            FileClose(FileNumber)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TimerLoad_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TimerLoad.Tick
        Dim timeDifferance As TimeSpan = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime)
        Dim newDate As DateTime = timeDifferance.ToString
        Label1.Text = newDate.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        ListBox1.Items.Add(Label1.Text)

    End Sub

    Private Sub login_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object,
                              ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown

        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then

            ListBox1.Items.Add(Label1.Text)
            If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then startTime = DateTime.Now
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You are saying that you are using another program, press any key and expect the login_KeyDown event to be triggered? This will not happen. Events are internal for the given program (the one in the code above) and, more specifically, related to certain controls. The event you are referring will only be triggered if the main form is selected when you press the given key. To accomplish what you want, you have to rely on hooks.

Comment: How would I use hooks to do what I need it to?

Comment: I will post you a sample code to get specific keys (never tested with 4.5 will do it now).

Comment: Where sorry? Thanks btw

Comment: Sorry to be pushy but how do I add a hook?

Comment: I was writing my reply (seriously, why you people are so impatient :)). "Where" I meant that never tried with .NET 4.5, did it now. Open a new VB.NET project, write this code and see how the marked point (the one INSIDE THE CONDITION, the WndProc is reached regularly) is reached every time you click on q.

Comment: Check this out: [Keylogger using Managed DirectInput](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ArticleVersion.aspx?aid=421883&av=607762).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a sample code showing you how to hook when a key is being pressed:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class Form1
    Private Const WM_HOTKEY As Integer = &H312
    Private Const MOD_ALT As Integer = &H1
    Private Const MOD_CONTROL As Integer = &H2
    Private Const MOD_SHIFT As Integer = &H4
    Private Declare Function RegisterHotKey Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal id As Integer, ByVal fsModifier As Integer, ByVal vk As Integer) As Integer
    Private Declare Function UnregisterHotKey Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal id As Integer) As Boolean

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
        If (m.Msg = WM_HOTKEY AndAlso m.WParam = CType(0, IntPtr)) Then
                If (m.LParam = 5308416) Then
                    MessageBox.Show("You pressed Q")
                ElseIf (m.LParam = 4521984) Then
                    MessageBox.Show("You pressed E")
                End If
        End If

        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        UnregisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 0)
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 0, Nothing, Keys.E)
        RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 0, Nothing, Keys.Q) 'RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 0, MOD_CONTROL, Keys.Q)
    End Sub
End Class
```

You have to evolve this (simple) code to include as many keys as you wish. The proceeding is quite easy:

1. Call `RegisterHotKey` for each key you want to hook. Bear in mind that
   you have also the option to hook combinations (CTRL+key,
   CTRL+SHIFT+key, etc.), I let a comment showing how to do
   that.
2. The code reached when the key is pressed is inside the condition where I wrote "'Reached every...". If you have more than one key, bear in mind that any press of any (registered) key will reach there and thus you have to know which one is every time. You can do that via `m.LParam` (each key has a different value for this property), you can do it manually (hardcoding the value you see for each key) or do some research (will not take you too long).

Comment: I got these errors when trying to use that; http://gyazo.com/d089cb521ffd34d812b97c507a8c52f4

Comment: @user2665617 Open VS 2012, select New->Project->Visual Basic->Windows->Windows Forms Application and paste this code in. It should work fine. That is, open a new winforms VB.NET project and copy all this code (don't put it in yours... you can adapt it later).

Comment: @user2665617 SURE YOU CAN. My recommendation was for you get used to it, to know what it does and then adapt it your project (pretty straightforward). The errors you are referring derive from having copied the code without understanding it and thus doing it wrongly. Firstly you should make sure that it works and that you can hook more keys, etc.

Comment: I really can't understand it... I'm new to .NET and stuff so this looks quite abnormal to me.

Comment: @user2665617 Don't worry. Just do step by step. Open the new project where you copied the code, write Dim test As String = "" where it says "'Reached every time q is pressed" and put a break point on this line. Run the code and see how this line is reached when you press q.

Comment: It doesn't do anything :/

Comment: @user2665617 it does, believe me. Replace Dim test As String = "" with MessageBox.Show("You pressed q") and now you can execute it with the code opened or from the .exe file, no matter. Once it is executing, press q and see a message box popping up.

Comment: Ah yes, that works http://gyazo.com/0cc611d66b528ac627670032903f67ac , what should I do next?

Comment: @user2665617 Excellent. Now copy RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 0, Nothing, Keys.Q) and change Keys.Q with any other letter to see that you can hook any letter. You can even open a text editor and start writing on it and when the hooked-letters are pressed, the message will appear.

Comment: Ok so how do I make key E only display "You pressed Key E" not "You pressed Key Q" then it opens "You pressed Key E"

Comment: @user2665617 If now both E and Q are hooked you have to account for their specific m.LParam value. I will update my code to make it work with these two cases. This should be enough to teach you have to deal with different keys.

Comment: @user2665617 there you have it.

Comment: @user2665617 put the Imports bit on the top (over Public Class MainForm). Right below Public Class MainForm put all the private const/declare function. Right below this copy the whole Protected Overrides Sub WndProc (logically also outside any function/sub, it is a sub itself). Copy the register bits to your form_load event (MainForm_Load) and create a new closingForm event method where you will copy  UnregisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 0). If you don't know how to do this last part, just copy the Form1_FormClosing as it is (replace "Form1" with "MainForm") just for consistency.

Comment: I did it as best I could following your instructions but I get errors when I do it like this http://paste.ubuntu.com/5963854/

Comment: @user2665617 Fourth line: what means "Emd Class" ?! Delete that.

Comment: @user2665617 Class Form1??!! When I said that you that have to copy my whole class. Form1 is like yours but with a different name!!

Comment: @user2665617 OK. Let's start from the top. Please, pay attention.

Comment: @user2665617 stop sending captures. You have lots of errors. Let's go line by line. Delete all what you have written and start from your original project.

Comment: My project before I added the Hooks? Ok I'm on that.

Comment: @user2665617 Ok. Add Imports on the top and then right below Public Class MainForm all the Private Const and Private Declare Function, nothing else.

Comment: @user2665617 in your original code you had MainForm_Load, don't delete it. Put inside of it what is inside of my Form1_Load (the RegisterHotKey calls). And also copy Protected Overrides Sub WndProc (as it was in your last capture, it is OK).

Comment: @user2665617 once you are done with that, run the code and confirm that everything works fine.

Comment: wait do I put it after MainForm_Load ?

Comment: @user2665617 The position of the functions/sub does not matter as far as they are in the right location (inside a Class).

Comment: @user2665617 if you have doubts show what you have done so far.

Comment: @user2665617 perfect. This code should already run fine. But it is pending unregistering the hooks when the form is closed. Create a formClosing method if you know how to do that or copy Private Sub Form1_FormClosing by changing its name to MainForm_FormClosing (it would work anyway but it is for making everything consistent). And you are done!

Comment: @user2665617 seriously do you hate me? I am a pretty nice guy (some times) :)... can you please explain me why have you written form1 again!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @user2665617 could you please indicate me the exact line where I said "copy form1"?

Comment: I don't write anything! :/ It's just the way it starts and when I change it.

Comment: @user2665617 get the idea: it is not too difficult. There should be just one class, mine is called Form1, yours is called MainForm. You have just to use yours, not mine!!

Comment: @user2665617 Please, stop doing things. I will do it for you.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm so bad at this.

Comment: @user2665617 No problem. Although you should remember that this is for programmers (ideally good ones :)). I will help you this time but understand that this is not what this is site is meant for.

Comment: I am very appreciative of your help and support. I understand that's not what this website is for but I really am stuck.

Comment: @user2665617 paste this into your original project (with all the objects on it), replace all the code you have with that.

Comment: @user2665617 finally!! Now, please, award this as the right answer and try to learn from this code as much as possible. Also bear in mind that this question, a priori, wasn't the right one for this site; but on top of that having to explain so many things (indicating that you have quite a few lackss) = pretty bad; goes completely against what this site is about. Please respect this issue in the future.

Comment: @user2665617 PS: just to make the point completely clear. I only replied you and because you posted a not-too-simplistic code; but if I would have known of your limited knowledge before I wouldn't have helped you. The logical scenario for someone asking what you asked is getting lots of -1s. In the future, if you are in this situation (many -1s), don't take it badly and understand the point: telling you what to do step by step is not helping you; neither this is what I want to do/this site is for. Learn and, please, use this site as it is intended to be used.